# Guardar los datos en base de dato SQLSERVER

Tags: c#

Mi finalidad es al darle al button guarde mis datos en la base de datos SQL server pero me salta este errore revisado varias veces y todo esta correcto segun lo que e visto pero me sale este error "No se puede implementar el método o la operación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. EL código se comparte como texto, por favor. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que sea necesario usando el enlace Editar bajo la pregunta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Con esa imagen sola no se puede ver donde esta el problema, pero dado el error que te esta tirando, en algún lugar de esa clase estas llamando a un método que no esta implementado. Este método seguramente retorna algún valor pero esta vacío. Seguramente el proyecto esta compilando porque agregaste un `throw new NotImplmentedException();`.

Cada uno codifica a su gusto no, pero yo te recomiendo sacar, todo lo que es logica de negocio y comunicación con BD, del formulario. Te dejo un ejemplo de una clase que se comunica con la BD y utiliza el patron singleton para tener una sola instancia y poder usarla desde cualquier clase.

```
public class DBHelper
{
    private string string_conexion;
    private static DBHelper instance = new DBHelper();
    private readonly string pc = "Data Source="";Initial Catalog="";Integrated Security=True";

    private DBHelper()
    {
        string_conexion = pc;

    }

    public static DBHelper getDBHelper()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DBHelper();
        return instance;
    }



    // Resumen:
    //     Se utiliza para sentencias SQL del tipo “Select”. Recibe por valor una sentencia sql como string
    // Devuelve:
    //      un objeto de tipo DataTable con el resultado de la consulta
    // Excepciones:
    //      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
    //          El error de conexión se produce:
    //              a) durante la apertura de la conexión
    //  
    public DataTable ConsultaSQL(string strSql)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            cnn.ConnectionString = string_conexion;
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strSql;
            tabla.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            return tabla;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EXPLOTO EL HELPER", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.CloseConnection(cnn);
        }
    }
    
    
    // Resumen:
    //     Se utiliza para sentencias SQL del tipo “Insert/Update/Delete”. Recibe por valor una sentencia sql como string
    // Devuelve:
    //      un valor entero con el número de filas afectadas por la sentencia ejecutada
    // Excepciones:
    //      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
    //          El error de conexión se produce:
    //              a) durante la apertura de la conexión
    //              b) durante la ejecución del comando.
    
    public int ejecutarSQL(string strSql)
    {
        int afectadas = 0;

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlTransaction t = null;

        try
        {
            cnn.ConnectionString = string_conexion;
            cnn.Open();
            //comienzo de transaccion...
            t = cnn.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strSql;
            cmd.Transaction = t;
            afectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Commit de transacción...
            t.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (t != null)
            {
                t.Rollback();
                afectadas = 0;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("EXPLOTO EL HELPER", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.CloseConnection(cnn);
        }

        return afectadas;
    }
    
     private void CloseConnection(SqlConnection cnn)
    {
        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cnn.Close();
            cnn.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```